# Pycharm не видит библиотеку pybrain

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, pybrain

Пользуюсь idea Pycharm.С помощью него установил библиотеку pybrain. После создание файла и импортирования в нём этой библиотеки ,-вылазит ошибка о том , что модуль не видно.

**Почему**  вылазит ошибка, и **какие** существуют способы решения проблемы ?

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/x/PycharmProjects/Community_Machine/Test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pybrain
  File "C:\Users\x\PycharmProjects\Community_Machine\venv\lib\site-packages\pybrain\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from structure.__init__ import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'structure'
```

Comment: Вероятно, модуль pibrain установился не в то окружение. Нужно больше входных данных

Comment: @Я установил модуль внутри окружения моего проекта

Comment: @gecube Другие модули при это работают!

Comment: а) конкретный текст ошибки -где?
б) в списке библиотек системных, локальных (получить можно через pip list) он есть? Стоит учесть, что в системе может быть минимум два разных интерпретатора пайтон разных версий (например, 2.х и 3.х)

Comment: @gecube а)Добавил в вопросе . б) Через pip list получить можно , я и в консоле Pycharm пробовал и в обычной . У меня установлено два разных интерпретатора пайтон  , но библиотека установлена на обои .

Comment: @gecube Я после этой ошибки , снова устанавливал другие библиотеки через Pycharm  , и все работает!

Comment: @gecube Может ли это быть баг pybrain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По ходу проблема в самом pybrain.

Solution есть по ссылке https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain/issues/201